# filter array based on ObjectId

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb

So I have 2 arrays here, let say

```
const users = [{_id:ObjectId("6274fb5b82bcc9b2ccc0a361"), name:p1, age:10}, 
               {_id:ObjectId("6274fbc382bcc9b2ccc0a362"), name:p2, age:15},
               {_id:ObjectId("6277a3d5b66c061096222bbd")}, name:p3, age:20];

const filterArray = [ObjectId("6274fbc382bcc9b2ccc0a362"),ObjectId("6277a3d5b66c061096222bbd")];
```

I want to filter result based on matching ObjectId, here's what I'm trying to do

```
const filteredUsers = users.filter(user=> !!filterArray.includes(user._id));
```

I'm expecting this result

```
filteredUsers = [{_id:ObjectId("6274fbc382bcc9b2ccc0a362"), name:p2, age:15},
                 {_id:ObjectId("6277a3d5b66c061096222bbd")}, name:p3, age:20]
```

Comment: you just need to convert those Object Ids to string using toString() and this should work just fine

Comment: Is this a mongodb question or a js question? It is written as a js question with a mongodb tag...

Answer (score 0):

You must convert it to string then filter it:

```js
const users = [
  { _id: ObjectId('6274fb5b82bcc9b2ccc0a361'), name: 'p1', age: 10 },
  { _id: ObjectId('6274fbc382bcc9b2ccc0a362'), name: 'p2', age: 15 },
  { _id: ObjectId('6277a3d5b66c061096222bbd'), name: 'p3', age: 20 }
]

const filterArray = [
  ObjectId('6274fbc382bcc9b2ccc0a362'),
  ObjectId('6277a3d5b66c061096222bbd')
]
const stringFilterArray = filterArray.map(item => item.toString())
const filteredUsers = users.filter(user => stringFilterArray.includes(user._id.toString()))
/* result
[
  { _id:ObjectId("6274fbc382bcc9b2ccc0a362"), name:p2, age:15 }, 
  { _id:ObjectId("6277a3d5b66c061096222bbd"), name:p3, age:20 }
]
*/
```